# Range input with textbox

Tags: javascript, html, input, range

thanks for your time!

Im looking something like this: Demo1. - http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php

I have this, but its not working.

```html
<form>
 <input id="valR" max="65" min="1" step="1" type="range" value="1">
 <input id="rangeValue" type="text" min="1" max="65" value="1" oninput="this.form.valR.value=this.value"></form>
<div class="tesxsss2"><div id="taxa">Taxa FS Connect: $15.00</div>
<div id="shipping">Priority Mail (frete): 43.51</div>
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You are very close with this code. The only problem is that you've put the oninput attribute on the wrong element.

You want to react to the range slider changing, not the value box.

Moving this to the valR element (and changing the id to reflect that we are now populating rangeValue) should fix your code:

```
<form>
    <input id="valR" max="65" oninput="this.form.rangeValue.value=this.value" min="1" step="1" type="range" value="1">
    <input id="rangeValue" type="text" oninput="this.form.valR.value=this.value"  min="1" max="65" value="1" >
</form>
```

[check out the pen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwoJVB)

Comment: Thanks! But doesnt work like i want. Because if i try to change the value in "RangeValue" the thumb doesnt go together. can you understand? Like, if i change the value, the thumb need to change too.
But i really appreciate! Thank you!

Comment: well that's just a case of putting an on input handler on your rangeValue element to do the same - see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You are missing in your script..Please find the below code.your slider is working

```js
let rangeValueElement = document.querySelector('#range');
document.querySelector('input#valR').addEventListener('change', showVal);

function showVal() {
  rangeValueElement.innerText = this.value;
 
}
```

```html
<input id="valR" max="65" min="1" step="1" type="range" value="1">

<span id="range" class="tesxss">1</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Lot simpler sollution

```html
<input id="valR" max="65" min="1" step="1" type="range" value="1" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.innerText = this.value;">
<span>1</span>
```